# away3d with transparent background over html content

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, away3d

Can I embed flash with away3d inside of it into html and have a transparent background?
All the information I've found refers to the inability due to restrictions of Stage3d.
But i saw working example.
Is there any way to achieve [this](http://clients.adrime.com/files/campaigns2/4320702299/42352/RU_slon.ru_20120614_index.html) result? ([swf alone](http://clientsmedia2.adrime.com/4320702299/42352/MPU_extended.swf))

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's an old version(right click it) of Away3D that doesn't run on Stage3D so it can be embedded with wmode=transparent. For the latest Away3D running in hardware mode you need wmode=direct... so it wouldn't work with transparency. If you want to do something simple like the banner on that site you can try an older version from the GIT repository.